# NSDateFormatter strange behavior for very old dates

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I am using NSDateFormatter in the following way:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = AUTORELEASE([[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]);

[formatter setDateStyle:dateStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:timeStyle];

return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

This returns me the correct date & time if the year in "date" is greater than **1893**. If I specify a date with an year < **1893** , It gives me wrong time but correct date.
The time usually has a difference of 7 min from the correct time.

Has anyone faced similar issues?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with how you create the NSDate object. How is that done.

Comment: I am calculating NSDate using dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970. It gives me the correct date. When I do a NSlog on date it gives me the expected date and time.

Comment: I suspect that if you study the history of timekeeping you'll discover that about then the Greenwich Observatory took over as the main adjudicator of time and corrected previous time standards.

Comment: @HotLicks Whoa. Love the history lesson! Awesome answer!

Comment: Actually, I can't find a specific action relating to 1893.  In 1890 GMT became the standard across the British Isles, and in 1883 "railroad time" largely took over in the US (though not until much later did "local time" get totally stamped out).  The choice of 1893 may have been somewhat arbitrary on the part of the Objective-C guys, since there often is no single event one can "blame" for such changes.