# Why is Calendar.date(from: DateComponents) adding time?

Tags: swift, date, swift3, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I create an instance of `DateComponents` using the following code:

```
let dateComponents = DateComponents(
            calendar: .current,
            timeZone: Calendar.current.timeZone,
            era: nil,
            year: nil,
            month: nil,
            day: nil,
            hour: 9,
            minute: 0,
            second: 0,
            nanosecond: 0,
            weekday: 2,
            weekdayOrdinal: nil,
            quarter: nil,
            weekOfMonth: nil,
            weekOfYear: nil,
            yearForWeekOfYear: nil)
```

I then print the `dateComponents` object and get the following (expected) output:

> calendar: gregorian (current) timeZone: Europe/London (current) hour: 9 minute: 0 second: 0 nanosecond: 0 weekday: 2 isLeapMonth: false

Immediately following this, I print the date created using the following code:

```
print(Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!)
```

To my great dismay and thorough unhappiness, the following is outputted:

> 0001-01-01 09:0**1:15** +0000

The `date(from: dateComponents)` function appears to have added just over a minute to the dateComponents before creating a date from them.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What's the point of creating a date that only has an hour and no other components? What's your goal?

Comment: You need to specify a date otherwise it will go back to year 1 and  have a huge time offset applied to it. Just choose something like era 1 year 2001 month 1 day 1

Comment: BTW you can omit the parameters you are not setting any value (nil is default) as long as you keep the same order.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm using it to hold information about a schedule that repeats daily or weekly, and therefore other components, like date and month aren't important to me.

Comment: @Leo Dabus it looks like it defaults to 1/1/2001, are you saying if I specify a date, ideally sooner, that would fix it? Thanks for the tip with parameters, I didn't know that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSDate` has some strange and undocumented behaviors for ancient dates. The change seems to have happened around 1895:

```
for year in 1890..<1900 {
    // January 1 of each year @ 9AM
    let dateComponents = DateComponents(
        calendar: .current,
        timeZone: Calendar.current.timeZone,
        year: year,
        month: 1,
        day: 1,
        hour: 9)

    if dateComponents.isValidDate {
        print(dateComponents.date!)
    }
}
```

My calendar is Gregorian and timezone is EDT (UTC -0500). This is the output:

```
1890-01-01 14:17:32 +0000
1891-01-01 14:17:32 +0000
1892-01-01 14:17:32 +0000
1893-01-01 14:17:32 +0000
1894-01-01 14:17:32 +0000 // not correct
1895-01-01 14:00:00 +0000 // correct
1896-01-01 14:00:00 +0000
1897-01-01 14:00:00 +0000
1898-01-01 14:00:00 +0000
1899-01-01 14:00:00 +0000
```

So for the years prior to 1895, Apple somehow added 17 minutes and 32 second to my time. You got a different offset, which is likely due your locale settings.

I couldn't find anything historical event about the Gregorian calendar in 1895. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685330/nsdateformatter-strange-behavior-for-very-old-dates) mentions that Britain started to switch over to GMT and the Greenwich Observatory started adjusting date/time standards across the British Isles in the 1890s so that may have accounted for this offset. Perhaps someone can delve into the source code for `Date` / `NSDate` and figure it out?

---

If you want to use `DateComponent` to store a repeating schedule, use `nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:)` to find the next occurance of your schedule:

```
let dateComponents = DateComponents(calendar: .current, timeZone: .current, hour: 9, weekday: 2)

// 9AM of the next Monday
let nextOccurance = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: dateComponents, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
```

Comment: In Germany, clocks were turned forward by 6 minutes and 32 seconds on April 1, 1893: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/germany/berlin?year=1893. Perhaps something similar happened in your time zone?

Comment: That's an interesting theory, guys - thanks. I'm using it to hold information about a schedule that repeats daily or weekly, and therefore other components, like date and month aren't important to me. Can you think of a better way of representing a schedule that can repeat daily, at a certain time, or weekly, on certain days and a certain time?

Comment: @LoicVerrall: instead of date you can use DateComponents and create Dates from them when needed. There was a great WWDC talk explaining this: "Performing Calendar Calculations". Though I cant find it online right now.