# Why does `ordinality(of: .day, in: .era, for: date)` give the same result for 2 dates in different time zones?

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar

Consider the following code:

```
import UIKit

let date = Date()

guard let nycTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST"),
  let nzTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "NZDT") else {
    fatalError()
}
var nycCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
nycCalendar.timeZone = nycTimeZone
var nzCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
nzCalendar.timeZone = nzTimeZone

let now = Date()

let nycDayOfEra = nycCalendar.ordinality(of: .day, in: .era, for: now)
let nycDayOfYear = nycCalendar.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: now)

var nzDayOfEra = nzCalendar.ordinality(of: .day, in: .era, for: now)
var nzDayOfYear = nzCalendar.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: now)
```

As I write this, NYC time and Aukland NZ time give different days. That's the case I'm interested in.

With the code above, the results for nycDayOfYear and nzDayOfYear are different (as of this writing I get nycDayOfYear=42 and nzDayOfYear=43.)

That is as expected, and as desired. (I was working to answer a "how do I calculate the number of days of difference in two Dates evaluated in different time zones?" question.)

However, it would take a bunch of messy adjustments to make the above day-of-year calculation and figure out the number of days of difference between those local dates when they span year boundaries.

I therefore tried to do the calculations using `ordinality(of: .day, in: .era, for: date)`.

However, the calculations based on calendar era give the same value regardless of the time zone of the calendar used to make do the calculation.

Why is that?

What would be a simpler way to calculate the number of **calendar days** difference between two dates **WHEN EXPRESSED IN DIFFERENT LOCAL TIME ZONES**? Like I said, my code that calculates the day of year would need additional logic added to handle dates that span calendar year boundaries.

Note that this is a different question than "How many days difference is there between 2 dates". In my question I want both dates to be expressed in different local time zones, and I'm interested in the difference in the calendar date of each of those date values.

Comment: "it would take a bunch of messy adjustments" Wait - why would it? Working out the difference between two dates originally expressed in different time zones is easy, because the NSDate _itself_, regardless of the _original_ time zone, is absolute.

Comment: What does *"number of calendar days difference between two dates WHEN EXPRESSED IN DIFFERENT LOCAL TIME ZONES"* mean? NSDate is an absolute point in time (as matt just said). "Number of days  between two dates" refers to a *specific* calendar and time zone.

Comment: Calendar calculations over "long" intervals can produce unexpected results, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/41860009/1187415 for another example. In your case,  `DateComponents(calendar: ..., era: 1).date!` returns "0001-01-01 04:56:02 +0000" for the NY calendar and "0000-12-31 12:20:56 +0000" for the NZ calendar, i.e. the difference is not just the difference of the time zones. – My *guess* is that "number of days in era" gives no sensible result.

Comment: Matt, read the description of the problem carefully. The goal is to figure out the number of calendar days difference between 2 dates when expressed in different time zones. The same `NSDate` is often 1 day different in NYC and NZ time zones, for example. See my answer to the "how to" part of the question, below.

Comment: Martin, I'm not sure how to phrase the question in a way that's clear. The problem I'm trying to solve is how to capture the fact that an NSDate can yield a different mm/dd/yyyy results depending on the time zone, and calculate the difference between 2 NSDates in "local mm/dd/yyyy terms".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martin's comment about calendar calculations over **long** intervals giving unexpected results is as good an answer as any as to why it doesn't work.

I did come up with code that calculates the desired difference in calendar date values between 2 dates expressed in specific time zones:

```
let date = Date()

guard let nycTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST"),
  let nzTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "NZDT") else {
    fatalError()
}
var nycCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
nycCalendar.timeZone = nycTimeZone
var nzCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
nzCalendar.timeZone = nzTimeZone

let now = Date()


let nycDateComponents = nycCalendar.dateComponents([.month, .day, .year], from: now)
let nzDateComponents = nzCalendar.dateComponents([.month, .day, .year], from: now)

let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day],
  from: nycDateComponents,
    to: nzDateComponents)

let daysDifference = difference.days
```

First I convert the 2 dates to month/day/year `DateComponents` values using calendars set to their specific time zone.

Then I use the Calendar function `dateComponents(_:from:to:)`, which lets you calculate the difference between 2 `DateComponents` values, in whatever units you want to use to compare them. (days, in this case)