# Swift 4 DateFormatter wrong timezone

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter, swift4

Starting Swift 4, I have one unit test that starts to fail. It seems that the timezone data I get is quite incorrect.

The following working code:

```
let f1 = DateFormatter()
f1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let d = f1.date(from: "1999-01-01")
let f2 = DateFormatter()
f2.dateFormat = "Z"
f2.string(from: d)
```

I'm in America/Los_Angeles, so I get `-0800`

If I swap 1999 to 1500 with this code:

```
let f1 = DateFormatter()
f1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let d = f1.date(from: "1500-01-01")
let f2 = DateFormatter()
f2.dateFormat = "Z"
f2.string(from: d)
```

I get `-075258`

Is this even a correct/allowed value? How can I get something valid for usage in a ISO 8601 ?

Comment: Why not try using the ISO8601DateFormatter that is available in the SDK?

Comment: Why would you need a time zone for dates 500+ years old? Any date with more than 100+ years (any date before 1914-01-01) you will get the same result

Comment: btw -075258 is the correct value. It means 7 hours 52 minutrs and 58 seconds. It considers a small calendar adjustment of 7m02s to those dates prior to 1914 at your location

Comment: This is a simplified piece of code. Timezone -075258 is not a valid ISO 8601 representation from my understanding. I will use the ISO8601DateFormatter then. I was using a this library that seems to have a bug: https://github.com/melvitax/DateHelper

Comment: Somewhat related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860009/why-is-calendar-datefrom-datecomponents-adding-time. And just for fun: `f1.date(from: "1895-01-01")` returns nil on my Mac. `1894-01-01` worked though!