# iOS Calendar.ordinality(of:in:for:) wrong results for month in era

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I am not sure if i am not grasping something here or it is a iOS SDK issue:

**Problem:** I need to get the difference in months from current month (eg: -1 for previous month). Following line work for any day except for the 1st and 2nd day of the month for any selected month.

I thought initially could be some kind of timezone or calendar aspect i didn't consider, but simplifying the problem (eg only using UTC), getting the month ordinality in current era for 2 different dates, one on 1st (or 2nd) of September 2020 and on for the 3rd i get different results.

```
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    let timezone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
    calendar.timeZone = timezone
    
    
    let dateMonthFirst = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: timezone, year: 2020, month: 9, day: 1))!
    // let dateMonthFirst = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1598918400) // same using directly timestamp for sept 1st
    let ordinalityFirst = calendar.ordinality(of: .month, in: .era, for: dateMonthFirst)!
    
    
    let dateMonthThird = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: timezone, year: 2020, month: 9, day: 3))!
    // let dateMonthThird = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1599091200) // same using directly timestamp for sept 3rd
    let ordinalityThird = calendar.ordinality(of: .month, in: .era, for: dateMonthThird)!
    
    
    print("1st of month ordinality: \(ordinalityFirst)")
    print("3rd of month ordinality: \(ordinalityThird)")
    print("MONTHS AGO: \(ordinalityThird - ordinalityFirst)")
```

Results are always

```
1st of month ordinality: 24236
3rd of month ordinality: 24237
MONTHS AGO: 1
```

when the expected result should be **24237 for both**

Am i missing something?

Note (1): the same "wrong" result can be obtained using the second day of the month, hence i would exclude timezone issues.

Note (2): for the same reason of 1, i doubt its also due to some effects of calendar alignment showed in this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41864214/691977

Comment: Try using year instead of era. Btw no need to mess with the timezone

Comment: Do you only need to get the difference in months between two dates? It would be much easier to get the first day of the month from both dates and get the difference between them.

Comment: Thanks, yes, i thought about using years, but it makes calculation on a very complex code base more complex, (we need ranges and dates operations spanning months over several years) and if possible i would like to avoid. More over, the era is already used pretty much everywhere and if there are issues to be considered would be nice to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is coming from the fact that you use `era` instead of `year`. As soon as you change the input for `in` to `.year`, you get the expected results. There's also no need to set the `TimeZone` and especially no need to do `calendar.locale = Locale.current`, since that's the default value of `Calendar.current.locale` anyways.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current    

let dateMonthFirst = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 2020, month: 9, day: 1))!
// let dateMonthFirst = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1598918400) // same using directly timestamp for sept 1st
let ordinalityFirst = calendar.ordinality(of: .month, in: .year, for: dateMonthFirst)!


let dateMonthThird = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 2020, month: 9, day: 3))!
// let dateMonthThird = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1599091200) // same using directly timestamp for sept 3rd
let ordinalityThird = calendar.ordinality(of: .month, in: .year, for: dateMonthThird)!


print("1st of month ordinality: \(ordinalityFirst)")
print("3rd of month ordinality: \(ordinalityThird)")
print("MONTHS AGO: \(ordinalityThird - ordinalityFirst)")
```

However, if you just need the difference in months between 2 `Date`s, there's a much easier solution: you simply need to use `calendar.dateComponents(_:from:to:)`.

```
calendar.dateComponents([.month], from: dateMonthFirst, to: dateMonthThird).month! // 0
```

This will give you the correct answer even if your dates are in different years.

```
let thisSept = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 2020, month: 9, day: 3))!
let nextAug = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 2021, month: 8, day: 3))!
calendar.dateComponents([.month], from: thisSept, to: nextAug).month! // 11
```

Comment: `DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2020, month: 9, day: 1).date!`

Comment: Thanks david, sadly refer to my comment in the question for the reason this is not the answer i need (and sorry yes, locale is a leftover, cleaning up)

Comment: @jalone check my edited answer, the 2nd solution should be the correct answer to your updated problem.

Comment: @jalone this is definitely how you should approach your issue. Forget about using era. As I mentioned I would just get the first day of the month and get the difference in month between the dates. If you are extra paranoid use noon. `Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2020, month: 9, day: 3, hour: 12).date!, to: DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2021, month: 8, day: 3, hour: 12).date!).month! // 11` Just omit the day to use the first day of the month

Comment: Thanks. I will wait a bit for a comprehensive answer regarding the era, and i will accept your answer